# Is it wrong to run my mail queue in the app pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, application-pool, smtpclient

We have to send automated emails. They need to be reliably dispatched, so we write them into the database. Simultaneously, a `System.Threading.Timer` that was started at `Application_Start` invokes a method every 30s to read out of the database and send then delete entries that have been sent. None of this occurs as a long-running task. Care has been taken to ensure that the process of clearing the db-queue uses async methods, so no phase of the sending/queuing ever blocks, with the whole process being performed by short-lived methods in the `ThreadPool`. The cost of an app recycle is also minimal (possibly resulting in the resending of a single email... not a problem).

Conventional wisdom says that running this in the web app is a not so good and I should spin this out to a service instead.

Writing services is a PITA. I'd rather avoid it if possible. So why shouldn't I run an efficient async mail queue in my app pool? Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Do you somehow indicate in the database that a given email has been picked up and is in the process of being sent?  If not, are you ever planning on running on multiple web servers?  If the answers to the above are "No" and "Yes", then you'll need a way to prevent both servers from sending the same batch of emails at the same time.

Comment: @ChrisShain, I'm aware of this and will change the architecture should the site evolve to the point that it outgrows its server.

Comment: Keep the Timer, I have made a similar Timer work job for my program and work super good the last 4 years - no problem at all, I even make idexing that takes 2 days work with a single thread and a timer. Also read : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: The next possible think is not to write a service but a simple net console program, and schedule it to run from windows scheduler (runing a console).

Answer (score 2):

If your site is not used your app pool will not be started - no mail is sent.

Comment: That's true. I wonder how bad it is to remove the timeout that shuts down the app pool after inactivity? We're the only app running on the machine in question.

Comment: I can't think of any immediate problems with removing the timeout. If your site is used that rarely so you need to worry about restart due to inactivity you need to think about other cases when app pool is shutdown/restarted (like reboot), but your site will not start automatically. Consider some external watchdog that will ping site periodically, even local scheduled task that simply GET page on the site will do.

Comment: its almost impossible the site to not be used - google read almost all sites every second.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Of course not for the intranet sites, How ever the application_start, always called on a pool recycle, or after the compile. I never see a case that is not called.

Answer (score 1):

> Writing services is a PITA

I guess that is subjective.  However, don't you think it would be beneficial to put it in a service?  In case you want to change your implementation, it's a lot easier to maintain smaller, individual components in my experience.  It usually becomes more of a PITA when you have everything in one place.

You are already writing the emails to a database.  It is very simple to write a simple Windows service that simply scans the database and sends emails.  I know this might not be ideal, but there are lots of examples floating around on SO and elsewhere.  You don't have to get all fancy and use an ESB (unless you want to).

So in the end, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should.*  You have to weigh the costs and benefits.